# Heisenberg's Uncertainity Principle Disproved?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Heisenberg's uncertainty principle states that we can't mutually determine both the trajectory and momentum of a subatomic particle.
According to Einstein,
If we take two particles with different masses,join them and let them spring apart.
Their velocities and positions will be related , so can we calculate both velocity and position?
IS the Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle disproved?

Comment: Answer to title: No.

Comment: No need to downvote. There is a good conceptual question here. This may help - [The more general uncertainty principle, regarding Fourier transforms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4)

Comment: That was the premise of the 1935 EPR paper.  As @TobiasFünke says: the answer is no.  That's because the uncertainty principle applies even to entangled particle pairs.  If you measure non-commuting observables on the individual particles, you get no additional information about the distant one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantum mechanics states that when you measure a particle's position or momentum there is a probability distribution over the possible outcomes. In any possible state, the probability distribution for the position and that for the momentum constrain one another. The standard deviation of the position $\Delta x$ and the standard deviation of the momentum $\Delta p$ are related so that
$$\Delta x\Delta p\geq\hbar/2$$
this is called the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle (HUP).

If particle 1 and particle 2 interact their states before and after the interaction satisfy the HUP. The position (or momentum) of particle 1 may be correlated with that of particle 2 so that the expectation values will be related, but the state of each particle will still satisfy the inequality above. You can't calculate their position and momentum because they don't have a single well defined position or momentum before or after the interaction, just a state that gives a probability distribution satisfying the HUP. Compared to the scale of everyday life the spread in position and momentum may be small so you may not be able to see it with the naked eye but that doesn't mean a particle is actually in some particular position.